# Input type date appearance in Safari on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile, webkit

I'm trying to use a regular input type date to use on mobile devices. But the width set in the CSS is overruled by Safari (or webkit).

I can add `-webkit-appearance: none;` to the CSS and by that, the width will work as expected. But then I lose all the other styling that is wanted, for example the arrow to indicate that it is a picker.

Is there a way that I can keep the basic styling of an input type date, but rule over the width myself?

Comment: An interesting question. I have been wondering as well why webkit behaves this way.

Comment: have you tried to add `important!`?

Comment: Also, take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615980/mobile-safari-text-input-width-bug

Comment: Yes, I've tried with !important but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 17):

`-webkit-appearance: none;` does always remove the typical style of a picker... But you can easily add an arrow using CSS and a background-image.

I'm not aware of a way to custom style the input but also keeping the arrow.

Comment: Yes, thats how I fixed this. It seems like an excessive way to just alter the width of the element, but there just might not be another way. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 10):

Add `-webkit-min-logical-width: <your desired value>`. It solved the problem for me!

Comment: It seems that the toggle arrow is placed outside of the element. So width=100% will make it to big.

Comment: If you use CSS calc and minus the 16px of the arrow this works perfectly. `-webkit-min-logical-width: calc(100% - 16px);`

Answer (score 8):

if you want select only `input[type='date']` and `input[type='time']`
try this CSS line.

```
input[type='date'], input[type='time'] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have found that to get 100% width correct as per @Boldizsar answer you need a little CSS calc action to remove the width added by the dropdown arrow on iOS.

```
-webkit-min-logical-width: calc(100% - 16px);
```