# Implementing Dynamic Date Picker Activation in React for iOS Using an Input Facade

Tags: javascript, html, ios, reactjs, safari

I need to create a date input field that supports also Safari iOS(13+) since in Google, Edge, etc the "placeholder" on Date input does not show "any text", it would switch the input type dynamically from text to date.

The code below works on Android, Google, Edge, as expected, but NOT iOS.

```
// facade component that renders a date input with your `placeholder`.
function CustomizedDateInput(placeholder) {
    const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState()
    const dateRef = useRef(null)

    const handleDateFormat = () = > {
        dateRef.current.type = 'text'
        //... other logic to format my text
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!dateRef.current) return
        
        if (isFocused) {
            dateRef.current.type = 'date'
            return
        }
        
        handleDateFormat()
    }, [])

    const handleFocus = () => {setFocused(true)}

    return (
        <input 
          ref={dateRef}
          type='date' 
          placeholder={placeholder} 
          onFocus={handleFocus}>
        />
    )
}
```

Other posts like [html5-date-picker-doesnt-show-on-safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35682138/html5-date-picker-doesnt-show-on-safari), and [input-type-date-appearance-in-safari-on-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381594/input-type-date-appearance-in-safari-on-ios) helped to figure out a way to make it work on other browsers and devices, but for iOS, when the user clicks the input, the keyboard shows instead of the datePicker itself. Since I need to cover iOS 13+ some HTML methods, like `showPicker` will not work for me. I also tried preventing default, changing the input type by using onFocus, onClick, but nothing workedout.